# Get variable using string

Tags: javascript, string

Lets say i have 2 arrays called fruitbasket01 and fruitbasket02.

I want to get the fruitbasket based on my id, which could be 01 or 02.

```
var fruitbasket01 = ['apple','orange'];
var fruitbasket02 = ['mango','grapes','peach','potato']
var id1 = '01';
var id2 = '02';

if (condition 1) {
     var string = 'fruitbasket'.concat(id1);
} else {
     var string = 'fruitbasket'.concat(id2);
}

for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
     /** more code here **/
}
```

may I know what is wrong with this method and how can I go about it instead.

Comment: you could put the arrays in an array or use an object with a key like your id.

Comment: my concern is about the for loop part, where i<string.length. Will that actually give me the length of the array or the length of the string itself

Comment: it's just the wrong concept with javascript, to use strings as accessor for variables. it does not work like $$ variables in PHP.

Comment: then how can I do this to access the array instead?

Comment: "potato" is not a fruit, does your code even compile?

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this

```
var fruitbasket = { 
    '01': ['apple','orange'], 
    '02': ['mango','grapes','peach','potato']
};

var id1 = '01';
var id2 = '02';

if (condition 1) {
     var string = fruitbasket[id1];
} else {
     var string = fruitbasket[id2];
}

for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
     /** more code here **/
}
```

Here string will be an array with the desired basket items

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) instead of single array, because the object is accessible with a key and easily maintainable.

```js
var baskets = {
        '01': ['apple', 'orange'],
        '02': ['mango', 'grapes', 'peach', 'potato']
    },
    id = '02';

console.log(baskets[id]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```